# Copy-assigning to a tuple from an iterator range in C++17

Tags: c++, iterator, tuples, c++17, fold-expression

I've been hoping to use new C++17 features like fold expressions and `std::apply()` to simplify some C++11 code I have that uses tools like `std::index_sequence` and `std::initializer_list` for some operations on tuples. One task in particular is giving me a bit of trouble: copying a range of values (e.g. from a `boost::tokenizer` object) to a tuple. I have a working solution that calls `std::apply()` on the tuple to which the values are to be assigned, but which still has to use `std::initializer_list` internally (for simplicity I've replaced the boost tokenizer iterators with a simple vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename Tuple, typename Iterator>
size_t copy_range_to_tuple(Tuple& tup, Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    size_t count = 0;
    auto copy = [&begin,&end,&count] (auto& value) -> bool {
        if (begin != end) {
            value = *(begin++);
            ++count;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    std::apply([&copy](auto&... values) {
        std::initializer_list<bool>{copy(values)...};
    }, tup);
    return count;
}

int main(int,char**) {
    std::tuple<int,int,int,int> tup;
    std::vector<int> x{4,3,2};
    std::cout << "copy count = " << copy_range_to_tuple(tup, x.begin(), x.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<3>(tup) << std::endl;
    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
copy count = 3
4
3
2
0
```

This is already a big win versus my C++11/14 code, which (due to the absence of `std::apply()`) used index sequences to match the iterators to the different tuple elements. However, I still have a feeling, or hope, that this could be simplified further with a fold expression, eliminating the need for initializer list. To be precise, I was hoping that I could make a fold expression that expanded `copy(values)`. Is that possible, or is there some other trick with modern C++ to make this less verbose? (Getting rid of the `copy` lambda would also be nice, but I think something like it is inevitable in order check for valid iterators).

Comment: Are you using tuple<T,T,...,T> with a uniform type a lot? std::array could be better suited.

Comment: @MarcGlisse No, I just made that the demo example for simplicity, but thanks for the suggestion. Since std::apply can take an std::array argument, I guess the above method could work generically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version with fold expression may look like:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int,int> t;
std::vector<int> v{4,3};
auto beg = v.begin();
auto end = v.end();
std::apply([&](auto&... values){
    auto getValue = [&](){ return (beg != end) ? *beg++ : 0; }; // returns 0 if range is too small
    ((values = getValue()),...);
}, t);
std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << std::endl; // 4
std::cout << std::get<1>(t) << std::endl; // 3
std::cout << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << std::get<3>(t) << std::endl; // 0
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4aTTn6)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can simply use an iterator and call `std::apply()`; I mean

```
auto it = v.begin();

std::apply([&](auto & ... values)
          { ((it != v.end() ? values = *it++ : values), ... ); }, t);
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<int,int,int,int> t;
   std::vector<int> v{4,3,2};
   auto it = v.begin();

   std::apply([&](auto & ... values)
             { ((it != v.end() ? values = *it++ : values), ... ); }, t);

   std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << std::endl; // 4
   std::cout << std::get<1>(t) << std::endl; // 3
   std::cout << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl; // 2
   std::cout << std::get<3>(t) << std::endl; // 0
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It noteworthy that this can be accomplished tersely, without the copy lambda function (and std::distance could be used to get the count of copied elements)